# How/Why does the 20% Refill only provide 10%?

Tags: mob-wars

Currently, I have a maximum of 2441 Energy.

The Energy Refill item that friends can send each other, claims to give a 20% refill to Energy, but I only receive 224 Energy from it, which is equal to roughly 10%.

Why do I only receive 224 Energy (9.18%), and not 488 (20%)?

Also, how do I then get it to give me the 20%?

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked [here](http://forums.metamoki.com/showthread.php?27290-problem-with-new-20-Energy-Refills-gifts).

And Clamps (Bob Maestri) gave the following answer :

> My first guess is that your attack and defense stats are too low to get the full 20% from the boosts. Please PM me your ID's and I will let you know.

If you keep on reading the conversation, you only get those 20% when your attack and defense stats are high enough, before that you get a lower percentage.

Comment: So how high does the stat(s) need to be?

Comment: Do they collectively need to be a certain amount, one of them only, or both?

Comment: the best I could find in forums is this :
"As Bob hasn't put the figure on there I would guess if you work on Attack + Dfence should equal 25% of your total energy and you'll be safe.
Your formula is working .
He reallocate some of my skills to solve the 20% issue and now it seems attack+defence is nearly 25% of my total energy ."